# Difference between Logistic regression in R & python

Tags: python, r, regression, logistic-regression

I have been creating Logistic regression in R and was now trying out the same in Python where i noticed it does not show the F statistics or Adjusted R values etc. We have a test to run the accuracy of the model and thats it. Is that how the model fitness is checked usually using Python ?

Comment: What package are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of methods to check model's performance in python (F1-score, precision, recall, accuracy). It depends on the library that you are using.

For instance, Scikit-learn is one library (not the only option). This link provides the list of possible metrics for performance measure in Scikit-lean http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics

Comment: Then you can use the link to choose the metrics you want